# Docker prune does not help in clearing space, docker-desktop-data seems to be not clearning

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying to clear my system of docker images, constantly pruning, even my latest prune said 22GB got freed, but when I look at my system, there is not even a single MB which got freed. My system is not on very low storage, I am positively sure there is so much 100's of GB of docker images in mine, which are not used. I need help clearing them, if anyone else also faced and resolved it.

> docker system prune -a

Above command is given and tried, not working
[image]

1. Software : Docker Desktop
2. OS       : Windows
3. WSL backend Docker running
4. From docker info, I could find Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker

Which is not present in any of my wsl like ubuntu, there is two docker wsl in my system, docker-desktop-data and docker-desktop. I am suspecting mostly due to this difference only. Someone help
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Does the following work?

```
docker rmi -f $(docker images -f "dangling=true" -q)
```

You can actually see what's being deleted that way.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).